# Conditionally set pino DestinationStream

Tags: node.js

Our Node.js server uses [pino](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pino) for logging and then writes its outpout to `stdout` which a C# microservice reads from and then writes to Splunk.

Right now, both `log.info()` and `log.error()` are being written to `stdout` and I was wondering if there was a way to conditionally set the `DestinationStream` for pino so that depending on the log, it would write to a different stream.

I have been looking through the API's, namely, [this](https://github.com/pinojs/pino/blob/master/docs/api.md#pino-destination) but have not been able to find a way to set the `DestinationStream` per log.

Comment: Are u trying to log to different destinations based on different log levels? I think I might have an answer for that

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure as to this is what you are trying.

so I can set multistreams to multiple destinations based on the log level. Here i have used filestream, feel free to use the choice of you stream
You can leave out the child part and stuff, that is to create a child worker and do the job of logging instead of the main process

```
getChildLoggerService(fileNameString): pino.Logger {
    const streams: Streams = [
      { level: 'fatal', stream: fs.createWriteStream(path.join(process.cwd(), './logs/database-connect-fatal.log'))},
      { level: 'error', stream: fs.createWriteStream(path.join(process.cwd(), './logs/database-connect-error.log'))},
      { level: 'debug', stream: fs.createWriteStream(path.join(process.cwd(), './logs/database-connect-debug.log'))},
      { level: 'info', stream: fs.createWriteStream(path.join(process.cwd(), './logs/database-connect-info.log'))},
    ];

    return  pino({useLevelLabels: true,
      base: {
        hostName: os.hostname(),
        platform: os.platform(),
        processId: process.pid,
        timestamp: this.appUtilService.getCurrentLocaleTimeZone(),
        // tslint:disable-next-line: object-literal-sort-keys
        fileName: this.appUtilService.getFileName(fileNameString),
      } ,
      level: this.appUtilService.getLogLevel(),
      messageKey: LOGGER_MSG_KEY,
      prettyPrint: this.appUtilService.checkForDevEnv(process.env.NODE_ENV),
      timestamp: () => {
        return this.appUtilService.getCurrentLocaleTimeZone()
      },

    }, multistream(streams)).child({
      connectorReqId: (process.env.REQ_APP_NAME === null ? 'local': process.env.REQ_APP_NAME)
        +uuid.v4().toString()
    });
  }
```

**UPDATE:**
I have also implemented this insdie Nesjs. Note that would anyways cause an overhead where the destination stream would need to passed in each method that requires the logger.

```
@Injectable({
  scope: Scope.DEFAULT,
})
export class PinoLoggerService {
  constructor() {}
  static logger(logLevel: pino.Level, destStream, context?: string, redactObj?: {}): pino.Logger {
    const opts = {
      // tslint:disable-next-line: object-literal-sort-keys
      messageKey: APP_CONST.COMMON.LOG.MESSAGE,
      logLevel: logLevel,
      serialziers: AppUtilService.setPropertiesToRedact(redactObj),
      base: {
        hostName: os.hostname(),
        platform: os.platform(),
        timestamp: AppUtilService.getDefaultTime(),
        // tslint:disable-next-line: object-literal-sort-keys
        fileName: context,
      },
    };
    return pino(opts, pino.destination(destStream));
  }
}
```

Here in each controller/service/pipe/interceptor (purely in the context of Nestjs) or any other util classes that needs a logger, then they can specify the destination stream.  This is a sample implementation I have in a decorator and use across different methods:

```
export const DatabaseErrorHandlerWithLogging = (context: string) => (
  target: any,
  property: string,
  descriptor: PropertyDescriptor
) => {
  const original = descriptor.value;

  descriptor.value = new Proxy(original, {
    apply: async function (target, thisArg, args) {
      let result;
     // this is just a static implementation service that fetches the logger based on context . It is provided below
      const infoLogger = ApiUtilService.getInfoLogger(reqId, context);
      const errorLogger = ApiUtilService.getErrorLogger(reqId, context);
      try {
        // leave out the reqID from the service input
        infoLogger.info('Service started with i/p:' + JSON.stringify([...args.slice(0, args.length - 1)]));
        const startTime = performance();
        result = await target.apply(thisArg, args);
        const endTime = performance();
        infoLogger.info(`Service completed: Execution time: - ${(endTime - startTime).toFixed(3)} ms`);
        //WARNING!!! - Test only
        // throw new Error('DatabaseException');
        return result;
      } catch (err) {
        errorLogger.error('Error occured when executing the db call:' + err.message);
       
      }
    },
  });
};
```

Inside ApiUtilService:

```
static getInfoLogger = (reqId: string, context: string) => {
    return PinoLoggerService.fetchCustomizedLogger('info', process.stdout, reqId, context);
  };

  static getErrorLogger = (reqId: string, context: string) => {
    return PinoLoggerService.fetchCustomizedLogger('error', process.stderr, reqId, context);
  };
```